# How to keep open the dropdown when i change pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm trying to keep open my dropdown when i have choose a page from the list but didn't work (I tried stopPropagation but it doesn't work with return).

JavaScript

```
$(".dropdown").on( "click", function() {
    var current_dropdown = $(".v-dropdown");
    $("[class^=v-dropdown]").not(current_dropdown).slideUp()
    current_dropdown.slideToggle();
    return false;});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a  class="dropdown" data-hover="title">title</a>
<ul class="v-dropdown2">
<li><a href="#" data-hover="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-hover="4">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you are using bootstrap from dropdown, then adding class 'open' to the wrapping div is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use local storage. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

When you toggle the dropdown, you can set a variable like this

```
        localStorage.setItem("dropdownIsOpen", true);
```

And you can read it like this

```
 if (localStorage.dropdownIsOpen === "true") {
   // add class
   }
```